# Find the sum of the following infinte series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$0<a<b<1$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{1/(k+b)}^{1/(k+a)} \frac{1}{1+x} \, dx$$

I found out the integral directly. But how to find sum? I've got suggestion that it can be tackled by telescoping technique, but couldn't find anything that gets cancelled.

Thank you.

Comment: If you've already computed the integral, then include that work in your question statement.

Comment: HINT $$1 + \frac 1{k+a} = \frac{k+a+1}{k+a}$$

Comment: @Semiclassical Integral is pretty obvious. We have a direct formula for that. That's why I didn't include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\int_{1/(k+b)}^{1/(k+a)} \frac{1}{1+x} \, dx \\
= \log(1 + 1/(k+a)) - \log(1 + 1/(k+b))  \\
= \log\frac{a + k + 1}{b + k+1} - \log\frac{a + k }{b + k}
$$
So here the telescoping comes in:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N} \int_{1/(k+b)}^{1/(k+a)} \frac{1}{1+x} \, dx 
= \log\frac{a + N + 1}{b + N+1} - \log\frac{a + 1 }{b + 1} \\
= \log(1 + \frac{a -b}{b + N+1} ) - \log\frac{a + 1 }{b + 1}
$$
Taking the limit $N \to \infty$ finally gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{1/(k+b)}^{1/(k+a)} \frac{1}{1+x} \, dx =   \log\frac{b + 1 }{a + 1}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.